# How can we use es6 modules in modern web browsers without transpiling the code

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Is it possible to use es6 module system and import modules in web browsers?

Comment: https://caniuse.com/es6-module

Answer (score 1):

With chrome 61, es6 module system is introduced to the world of web browsers. This link https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/modules can be referred for more details on how chrome implements the module system.

Some of the important features of es6 module system discussed in the above link are:

1. Modules by default are `strict` mode.
2. They are not lexical top-level scope, which is var foo = 42 in module file won't be available as window.foo.
3. Modules are included in html file as `<script type="module" src="example.mjs">`
4. Modules are deferred by default

There are some other browsers too which have come up with solutions in their different versions. This below-given link explains the compatibility level of module system in different browsers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility

Comment: the only current browser that doesn't, and never will, support modules is IE11

Comment: `Modules are included in html file as` really? that makes it appear like you have to write script tags for all module files. a) you don't, and b) what is this `.mjs` extension? something Chrome does differently? - hint, `.js` works just fine

Comment: .mjs is just used as the convention, it works just the same as .js extension. Chrome recommends using .mjs in aligning with node which mandates using .mjs for files using es6 modules

Comment: chrome isn't the standards committee